# How to make Dijkstra's algorithm report the full final distance for that shortest route

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm relatively new to python and have been reading on the internet on ways to implement Dijkstra's algorithm and I came across the code provided below on this page [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Python).

The code is an implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm and it works perfectly fine. see code below:

```
from collections import namedtuple, deque
from pprint import pprint as pp


inf = float('inf')
Edge = namedtuple('Edge', ['start', 'end', 'cost'])

class Graph():
    def __init__(self, edges):
        self.edges = [Edge(*edge) for edge in edges]
        # print(dir(self.edges[0]))
        self.vertices = {e.start for e in self.edges} | {e.end for e in self.edges}

    def dijkstra(self, source, dest):
        assert source in self.vertices
        dist = {vertex: inf for vertex in self.vertices}
        previous = {vertex: None for vertex in self.vertices}
        dist[source] = 0
        q = self.vertices.copy()
        neighbours = {vertex: set() for vertex in self.vertices}
        for start, end, cost in self.edges:
        neighbours[start].add((end, cost))
        #pp(neighbours)

        while q:
            # pp(q)
            u = min(q, key=lambda vertex: dist[vertex])
            q.remove(u)
            if dist[u] == inf or u == dest:
                break
            for v, cost in neighbours[u]:
                alt = dist[u] + cost
                if alt < dist[v]:                                  # Relax (u,v,a)
                dist[v] = alt
                previous[v] = u
        #pp(previous)
        s, u = deque(), dest
        while previous[u]:
            s.appendleft(u)
            u = previous[u]
        s.appendleft(u)
        return s
```

This is the test data provided:

```
graph = Graph([("a", "b", 7),  ("a", "c", 9),  ("a", "f", 14), ("b", "c", 10),
           ("b", "d", 15), ("c", "d", 11), ("c", "f", 2),  ("d", "e", 6),
           ("e", "f", 9)])
```

To run it for specific two points, say 'a' to 'e':

```
pp(graph.dijkstra("a", "e"))
```

Output looks like this:

```
deque(['a', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
```

My question is this, how can I make this algorithm report the full final distance for that shortest route. i.e. desired output to look something like this:

```
deque(['FullDistance', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
```

I've been trying adding 'dist' to the append at the end of function 'Dijkstra' but doesn't seem to work, I don't get anything different:

```
s.appendleft(dist)
```

It's probably something simple somewhere to tweak but I can't seem to figure it out, any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need to add alt instead of dist.

try this at the end of your function

```
s.appendleft(alt)
```